# How do I add a library to a Stack project? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, random, haskell-stack

I know this question has probably been asked a thousand times, but I'm currently learning Haskell, and I'm making a little random number generator / guessing game. I got all the terminal input and output working, and started trying to figure out random number generation, and I can't figure it out. First, I tried adding the random library to the .cabal file, and whenever I ran stack build, it removed it from the file. Then, I tried putting it into the stack.yaml file. After deleting the lock file, and putting it in there, it compiled without an error. So, I tried importing it with import System.Random like I've seen everywhere else, and it didn't work. I tried asking a question on the Github repo, but nobody answered my question.

Comment: FYI stack has a [user guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies) which answers this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `package.yaml` file in your directory? Stack will (re-)generate your `.cabal` file from it every time it runs. So:

- Add the dependency in `stack.yaml` only if the library is not on Stackage or you want a different version.
- Add the dependency in `package.yaml`.